# Error: Package does not exist

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a little problem in Eclipse with a package . The error output is Package (name of package ) does not exist .

I have a package called `de.baimos.blueid.lockserver.demo.exec` . But Eclipse is looking for a package called `de.baimos.blueid.lockserver.api.exec` . This package is can be found in my Project nowhere .

My current situation is this: I have two projects that work as a project. Now you can in Eclipse under Properties - Add a project to a different > Project -> Java Build Path . But if I want to run Maven install I get the error above. At first I thought it would be in the pom.xml file . But I noticed that it is not possible to merge two pom.xml files. My project was to make the inheritance , however, by themselves , whom I put them together leads . Did anyone of you ever such a problem , or can someone help me ?

Thanks in advance for your help .

That is the error:

```
[ERROR] /home/test/workspace/HeartbeatService/src/main/java/de/baimos/blueid/lockserver/demo/exec/DemoCommandExecutionEventListener.java:[3,44] error: package de.baimos.blueid.lockserver.api.event does not exist
[ERROR] /home/test/workspace/HeartbeatService/src/main/java/de/baimos/blueid/lockserver/demo/exec/DemoCommandExecutionEventListener.java:[4,44] error: package de.baimos.blueid.lockserver.api.event does not exist
[ERROR] /home/test/workspace/HeartbeatService/src/main/java/de/baimos/blueid/lockserver/demo/exec/DemoCommandExecutionEventListener.java:[5,44] error: package de.baimos.blueid.lockserver.api.event does not exist
[ERROR] /home/test/workspace/HeartbeatService/src/main/java/de/baimos/blueid/lockserver/demo/exec/DemoCommandExecutionEventListener.java:[6,44] error: package de.baimos.blueid.lockserver.api.event does not exist
[ERROR] /home/test/workspace/HeartbeatService/src/main/java/de/baimos/blueid/lockserver/demo/exec/DemoCommandExecutionEventListener.java:[8,59] error: cannot find symbol
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maven can't see what you specify in Eclipse's Java Build Path; it's a command line tool that runs outside / without Eclipse.

Instead, you have to do `mvn install` in the first project.

Then you can add a dependency to this project in the second project's POM.

Maven will then make sure that Eclipse add the first project to the classpath as well without manually changing the build path in the UI.

Comment: How can I make a dependency to the main project? I have tried from the pom.xml of the first project manually add the properties in the other Pom but this does not work.

Is there an easy way to add the dependency?

Comment: Add a `<dependency>` element. Read the section "The POM" here: http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html

Comment: Hallo ich habe gerade gsehen das Sie aus der Schweiz sind. Können Sie auch deutsch reden? Das würde es mir einfacher machen. Gruss

Comment: Thank you. The problem has thus been clarified. But now there is another new problem. That looks like this:

Failed to execute goal on project Heartbeat Service: Could not resolve dependencies for project web service client: Heartbeat Service: was :0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact de.baimos.blueid.lockserver: api: jar: TRUNK-SNAPSHOT at specified path / home / test / workspace / Heartbeat service / lib / LockServer-sdk.jar -> [Help 1]

Comment: Why does maven think it should look at `path / home / test / workspace / Heartbeat service / lib / LockServer-sdk.jar`? Dependencies should be in `~/.m2/repository/`.

Comment: @user3355347: You're not the only person visiting this site. To make the question more useful, we'll stick to English :-)

Comment: <dependency>
         <groupId>de.baimos.blueid.lockserver</groupId>
         <artifactId>api</artifactId>
         <version>TRUNK-SNAPSHOT</version>
         <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/lockserver-sdk.jar</systemPath>
         <scope>system</scope>
        </dependency>

Comment: Thats my dependency. for the lockserver-sdk.jar

Comment: In that case, the path is wrong. Note that paths are case sensitive (you used LockServer and lockserver which isn't the same thing).